# I cant able to open flutter_console.bat file

Tags: android, flutter

cant able to open flutter_console.bat file while installing flutter

already tried setting up path on environmental variables and work with IDE

'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH

Comment: Have you tried referring this documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install?

Comment: Yeah i tried this, But flutter_console is not working

Comment: Have you downloaded this https://git-scm.com/download/win . If yes, then just provide a git path where your git is installed. Or easier uninstall and reinstall git.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem. Try these steps.

To open the flutter console open using 'Run as Administrator"

Next you have to check the paths.

1. C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;
2. C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
3. C:\Windows\System32;

Then run flutter doctor. It should work. 
Then add the android studio sdk paths.
Follow the instructions in this [link](https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/).

Finally open Android Studio and go to Settings-> Plugins and install Flutter and Dart.
Then restart Android Studio. Then you will be able to open your first Flutter project.